# подскадите как добавить данные, что бы каждую итерацию не затирлось то, что уже есть

Tags: php

```
                     $md5Hashes = json_decode(file_get_contents(Yii::getAlias($this- 
                    >forms_path) . $file), true);

                    $this->configs['md5'];
                    foreach ($this->configs['md5'] as $key => $value) {
                        $md5Hashes = ($this->configs['md5'][$key]);
                   //не выходит
                  ------------------------
                          $md5Hashes = [];
                    foreach ($this->configs['md5'] as $key => $value) {
                        $md5Hashes[$key] = $value;
                    }
```

Comment: было бы логично и цикл сюда добавить. возможно вам нужно сложить все в массив. `$md5Hashes[] = ...`

Comment: @teran замчем массив?

Comment: чтобы не затиралось, то что уже есть. Конкретизируйте свой вопрос, напишите что именно у вас затирается, и что вы хотите получить.

Comment: @teran На данный момент там ассоциативный массив, данные должны обновляться а не стираться

Comment: @teran Добавил цикл, пытался и так и так, приходит пустой массив